# Propagating Error messages in Google Cloud Platform (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am building a near real time service.  The input is a cloud storage bucket and blob path to a photo image.  This horizontally-scalable service is made up of multiple components including ML models running on k8s and Google Cloud Functions, each of which has a chance of failing for a variety of reasons.  The ML models are independent and run in parallel.  Each component is triggered by a PubSub push message topic unique to the component.  Running the entire flow for one photo may take 15 seconds.

I want to return a meaning error message back to the service requester telling which component failed if there is a failure.  Essentially, I want to report which image failed and where it failed.

What is the recommended practice for returning an error back to the requester?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in service for this. But, because you already use PubSub for asynchronous call, I propose to use it also to push back the error.

You can do this in 2 flavors

First, create a PubSub topic for the errors, let's say 'error_topic'

**1. Without message customization**

- In the PubSub message, the requester put which it is in the attribute (let's say 'requester' attribute name)
- In the consumer service, if an error occurs, return an error code (500 for example) for push subscription or a NACK in pull subscription.
- Configure the PubSub subscription to manage retry and [dead letter topic](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/dead-letter-topics) (the dead letter topic is 'error_topic')
- Then, create one subscription per requester on the 'error_topic' (use the [filter capability for this](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/filtering)) and consume the message in the requester services

**2. With message customization**

- In the PubSub message, the requester put which it is in the attribute (let's say 'requester' attribute name)
- The consumer service that raises the error create a new message with custom information and copies the 'requester' attribute value and then puts it in attribute of the message in the 'error_topic' (let's say 'original_requester' attribute name).
- Then, create one subscription per requester on the 'error_topic' (use the [filter capability for this](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/filtering)) and consume the message in the requester services